# Retornar imagen con react-data-table-component en React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datatables, react-hooks

Los datos estan llegando correctamente, pero al usar DataTable no encuentro la forma de retornar correctamente las imagenes y demas propiedades de DATA.

Estoy usando react-data-table-component para poder paginar la lista de imagenes a partir de aplicar Destructuring a un array y posteriormente con una arrowFunction accedo a las imagenes

```
import React from 'react';
//Se importa datatable
import Datatable from 'react-data-table-component';

 //DataTable
 const columnas=[
    {
      name: 'ID',
      selector: 'id',
      sortable: true
    },
    {
      name:'Imagen',
      selector:'imagen',
      sortable: true
    }
  ]
  
const Fotos = ({data}) => {
   

    //extraer la data
    const {id,sol,camera,img_src,earth_date,rover}=data;

    //Estoy accediendo a las imagenes con una arrow function
    const imgRover = ({ img_src}) => <img src={img_src} />;

    return ( 
        <div className="card-image">
            <Datatable
            columns={columnas}
            data={data}
            //Aquí retorno las imagenes
            expandableRowsComponent={<imgRover/>}
            />
        </div>
     );
}
 
export default Fotos;
```

Componente ListarFotos

[image: Listar fotos]

Con `expandableRowsComponent={<imgRover/>}`  me muestra los 4 elementos de la imagen anterior; sin embargo muestra "There are no records to display"

[image: Retorno de las fotos]

Por el contrario si no uso DataTable, quedaria de la siguiente forma, sin embargo quiero usar DataTable para poder paginar las imagenes obtenidas.

```
import React from 'react';

const Fotos = ({data}) => {
    //extraer la data
    const {id,sol,camera,img_src,earth_date,rover}=data;

    return ( 
        <div className="card-image">
            <img src={img_src} />
            <span className="card-title">{camera.full_name}</span>
        </div>
     );
}
 
export default Fotos;
```

Answer (score 0):

Si ya hiciste el destructure y obtuviste `img_src`, creo que te serviría algo así:

```
//extraer la data
const {id,sol,camera,img_src,earth_date,rover}=data;

//Estoy accediendo a las imagenes con una arrow function
const imgRover = () => (<img src={img_src} />);

return ( 
    <div className="card-image">
        <Datatable
        columns={columnas}
        data={data}
        //Aquí retorno las imagenes
        expandableRowsComponent={imgRover()}
        />
    </div>
 );
```

UDPATE:

Creo que deberías de leer un poco mejor la documentación de `react-data-table-component`, veo que tienes estos errores:

1.Cuando defineslas columnas, defines una que tiene como selector `imagen`. Sin embargo en tu objeto de entrada `data` solo tienes img_src.

2. Usas `expandableRowsComponent` pero nunca pasas el prop que activa dicha funcionalidad que es `expandableRows`.

3.Si lo que quieres es un Row que contenga la imagen ¿Porqué la defines como columna en primer lugar?

En caso de que quieras que solo aparezca el ID y la imagen en una fila expandible, has esto:

```
import React from 'react';
//Se importa datatable
import Datatable from 'react-data-table-component';

 //DataTable
 const columnas=[
    {
      name: 'ID',
      selector: 'id',
      sortable: true
    }
  ]
  
const Fotos = ({data}) => {
   

    //extraer la data
    const {id,sol,camera,img_src,earth_date,rover}=data;

    return ( 
        <div className="card-image">
            <Datatable
            columns={columnas}
            data={data}
            //Aquí retorno las imagenes
            expandableRows
            expandableRowsComponent=<img src={img_src} />
            />
        </div>
     );
}
 
export default Fotos;
```

Si necesitas entender como funciona la librería, ingresa [a este](https://codesandbox.io/s/z6gtg?file=/src/index.js) sandbox y mira como el autor utiliza el módulo.

Comment: Acabo de añadir tu sugerencia, sin embargo me sigue marcando "There are no records to display"

Comment: He actualizado la respuesta, espero que te sea de ayuda.

Comment: Gracias,aun me sigue mostrando "There are no data dsplay" y veo que despues de expandableRowsComponent= marca que espera una { y no < es decir de esta forma: expandableRowsComponent={img_src};pero aun estando así sigue persistiendo el mensaje